# Prove the integral is always imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, greens-theorem, cauchy-integral-formula

Show that if f is analytic on D and γ is a closed curve in the region then the integral
$$\int \overline{f(z)}f'(z)$$
is purely imaginary.
I think this problem would use some extension of cauchy integral formula. I know that f'(z) is analytic but don't know much about $$\overline{f(z)} $$. Someone suggested to use Green's theorem here but I can't figure out how to do that.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f = u + iv$ then $\bar{f}f' = (u - iv)(u_x + iv_x) = (uu_x + vv_x) + i(uv_x - vu_x)$. So

\begin{align}\bar{f}f'\, dz &= [(uu_x + vv_x) + i(uv_x - vu_x)](dx + i\, dy)\\
& = [(uu_x + vv_x)\,dx - (uv_x - vu_x)\, dy] + i[(uu_x + vv_x)\, dy + (uv_x - vu_x)\, dx]
\end{align}

Since $$\Re\int \overline{f(z)}f'(z)\, dz = \int \Re\{\overline{f(z)}f'(z)\, dz\}$$ the result will be proved if we show that $\Re\{\bar{f}f'\, dz\}$ is an exact differential. As $f$ is analytic, $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. Thus $uv_x - vu_x = -uu_y - vv_y = -(uu_y + vv_y)$ and

$$\Re\{\bar{f}f'\, dz\} = (uu_x + vv_x)\, dx + (uu_y + vv_y)\, dy = d\left(\frac{u^2 + v^2}{2}\right)$$

So $\Re\{\bar{f}f'\, dz\}$ is exact.

Comment: Can you please explain how does the integral become only imaginary if the real integral is exact? Is it because if it is exact then the integral in the closed loop will be zero?

Comment: @User123 yes, you have the idea.